# How to call MySQL source data for jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete, and want to have a separate PHP file to house the data, instead of creating a variable (i.e. var availableTags = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green, "Blue"]).

However, when doing this, the autocomplete will continually display all of the available options, and not filter out what the user types in.

Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: "../../db/autocomplete_list.php"
    });

});
```

autocomplete_list.php

```
require_once('../includes/connect.php');
$dbh = connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,CM_DATABASE);

$colors = '[';

$sth = $dbh->query ("SELECT * FROM constants 
                     WHERE category='Colors' 
                     ORDER BY display");

while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { 

    $colors.= '"'.$row[value].'", '; 

}

$colors = rtrim($colors, ', ');

$colors .= ']';

print $colors;
```

execution of autocomplete_list.php

> ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green, "Blue"]

## EDIT:

Have updated my autocomplete_list.php file to the following.  However, now the autocomplete isn't displaying my values.  If I check the response in FireBug, it is showing the results correctly, it just appears that they aren't being passed back to the autocomplete.

```
require_once('../includes/connect.php');
$dbh = connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,CM_DATABASE);

if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $mysearchString = $_GET['term'];
}

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT category, value, display FROM constants 
                    WHERE category = 'COLORS' AND value LIKE '$mysearchString%'
                    ORDER BY display");

while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { 
    print $row['display']."\n";         
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on the page?

Comment: No errors.  Have FireBug open, and nothing.  "GET dev.sample.com/db/autocomplete_list.php?term=l" with response of "Yellow", "Blue".

Comment: It should look like an array in the console. Is that the case?

Comment: json_encode with php and decode with jquery

Comment: I figured it out, and posted an answer below!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here:

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/

```
require_once('../includes/connect.php');
$dbh = connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,CM_DATABASE);

$return_arr = array();

if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $mysearchString = $_GET['term'];
}

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT category, value, display FROM constants 
                    WHERE category = 'COLORS' AND value LIKE '$mysearchString%'
                    ORDER BY display");

while ($row = $sth->fetch PDO::FETCH_ASSOC()) { 

     $row_array = $row['display'];

     array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to reduce the possible options on server side:

```
$sth = $dbh->query ("SELECT * FROM constants 
                     WHERE category='Colors' and value like '.".$_GET['term']."%'
                     ORDER BY display");
```

(with $_GET['term'] replaced by a string checked against sql injections..)

see: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

Comment: Made the changes, but now the autocomplete is not displaying on my live form.  When I check the console on Firebug, it is calling everything correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`source` propery expect an array of values, not a string. Try to echo the content of "autocomplete_list.php" directly onto the script, something like this:

```
source: <?php include "../../db/autocomplete_list.php"; ?>
```

That will should work.

Comment: Thought about that, but you can't do a PHP include in Javascript.